# AngularJS Scope Object Inheritance

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi I need a AngularJS Wiz to point me in the right direction been trying to get my head around AngularJS Scope and Inheritance.
I have a child Scope which I add to a Parent Scope then I want to add a new object to the Parent scope via array.push(); but I'm not sure why the Child scope then inherits this new value. See the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/sjmcpherso/EFxuZ/ The first example using ng-repeat and objects causes the child to update:

```
$scope.childArr = [{'name':'peter'},{'name':'paul'},{'name':'perry'}];
$scope.parentArr = $scope.childArr;
$scope.parentArr.push({'name':'Why am I in now in the Child Array?'})
```

Whereas the second example using just a variable does not:

```
$scope.childVar = "Confused Muchly";
$scope.test.parentVar = $scope.childVar;
$scope.test.parentVar = "This wont change the child variable";
```

Ideally I would like to make changes to the child scope which would update the parent scope but not the other way around.

I have read of https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes while not fully understanding everything this issue seems a mystery to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, both of your models `$scope.childArr` and `$scope.test.parentArr` are in $scope of the controller. None of them is in parent scope.

If you want to have `parentArr` in the parent scope, then you should have a parent-child controller design or move your model inside the `rootScope`:

```
$rootScope.test = {};
$rootScope.test.parentArr = [ /* some items here */ ];
```

Secondly, `$scope.childArr` and `$scope.test.parentArr` both point to the same array. Changing either of them would mean changing both of them.

It is almost same as doing:

```
$scope.test = {};
$scope.childArr = $scope.test.parentArr = [
    {'name':'peter'},
    {'name':'paul'},
    {'name':'perry'}
];
```

If you want to create separate copies so that changing one of them would not affect the other, then you can use **angular.copy()**:

```
$scope.test.parentArr = angular.copy($scope.childArr);
```

Comment: Thanks, yes my terminology is wrong they are in the same scope and yes i was ignoring JS prototype inheritance with the 2 objects and yes .copy() works perfectly. Thanks for clearing that up